# how to restrict the number of tweets returned from twitter api in backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, twitter

I'm trying to build a simple Backbone Twitter-based application that will show an overview of Recent tweets 
in the user’s timeline of the authenticated user’s account,
but each time i run the app there is 20 tweets returned from the twitter API and vertical scrolling appeared on 
the browser window which i dont prefer.
how could I restrict the number of tweets that appers on the page and instead of 20 tweets
how could I load 6 tweets for example and  make link in the bottom of the page load the rest of tweets.
My code is as follows:

My collection:

```
define(['backbone', 'app/model/Tweet'], function(Backbone, Tweet) {

var com = com || {};
com.apress = com.apress || {};
com.apress.collection = com.apress.collection || {};

com.apress.collection.Timeline = Backbone.Collection.extend({

//the model that this collection uses
model: Tweet, 
//the server side url to connect to for the collection
url: 'http://localhost:8080/timeline',

initialize: function(options){
    //anything to be defined on construction goes here
},
});

return com.apress.collection.Timeline; 
});
```

my view

```
define(['jquery', 'handlebars', 'backbone', 
'app/collection/Timeline'], function($, Handlebars, Backbone, Timeline) {

var com = com || {};
com.apress = com.apress || {};
com.apress.view = com.apress.view || {};

com.apress.view.TimelineView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: '#timeline',
template: Handlebars.compile($("#timeline-template").html()),
    timeline: null,
events: {
    'click .profile': 'showDialog'
},

initialize:  function(options){
    var self = this; 
    //create a collection for this view to render 
    self.timeline = new Timeline();//new 
    com.apress.collection.Timeline();
    //initial render 
    self.render();

    //force the fetch to fire a reset event
    self.timeline.fetch({reset:true 
        });

    self.listenTo(self.timeline, 'reset', self.render);

},

render: function(){
    var self = this; 
    if(self.timeline.models.length > 0){
        var output = self.template({tweet: self.timeline.toJSON()});

        self.$el.append(output);            
    }
    return self; 
},
showDialog: function(options){

    var self =this, 
        $target = $(options.currentTarget),
        username = $target.data('user'); 

    /** 
     * Reuse the profile view
     **/
    var profileView = new com.apress.view.ProfilePopupView
({user:username});

}

});
// export stuff:
return com.apress.view.TimelineView;
});
```

server.js

```
/**
* A simple API hosted under localhost:8080/books
*/
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var Twit = require('twit')

var client = null;
function connectToTwitter(){
 client = new Twit({
  consumer_key:         '********'
, consumer_secret:      '********'
, access_token:         '*******'
, access_token_secret:  '*******'
 });
 }
 //get the app to connect to twitter.
 connectToTwitter();
 /*app.get('/', function(req,res)
 { 
 res.sendfile('index.html');
  }
 );*/
 /** 
 * Get the account settings for the user with the id provided.
 **/
 app.get('/profile/:id', function(request, response){

 response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 

 client.get('users/show', {screen_name:request.params.id},
 function (err, reply) {

  if(err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    response.send(404);

  }
  if(reply){
   /// console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    response.json(reply);
  }

 });
});

/**
 * Returns the twitter timeline for the current user 
**/
app.get('/timeline', function (request, response) {

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); 
 client.get('statuses/home_timeline', { },  function (err, reply) {

  if(err){
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
    response.send(404);

  }
  if(reply){
 //   console.log('Reply: ' + reply);
    response.json(reply);
  }

 });



});


//additional setup to allow CORS requests 
var allowCrossDomain = function(req, response, next) {
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "http://localhost");
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
'OPTIONS,GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

if ('OPTIONS' == req.method) {
  response.send(200);
}
else {
  next();
}
};

app.configure(function() {
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
//Parses the JSON object given in the body request
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.static('../client'));

});

//Start server
var port = 8080;
app.listen( port, function() {
console.log( 'Express server listening on port
%d in %s mode',port,app.settings.env );
});
```

my entry point to the app

```
 $(function() {

  var timelineView = new com.apress.view.TimelineView()
  }
```

my html

```
  <div id='timeline' class='timeline-view'>
             <h2>My Tweets</h2>
 </div>

 <!-- Template for timeline -->

 <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="timeline-template">
 <ul class='listview fluid'>
    {{#each tweet}}
  <li>
      <div class='icon'>
          <img src='{{user.profile_image_url}}'></img>
    </div>
        <div class='data'>
            <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
            <p>{{format text}}</p>
            <p class="timestamp"><i>{{friendlyDate}}</i></p>
        </div>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

Please teach me how should I fix it.

Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is vertical scrolling, in the afterRender method, render but hide the rows after #6. 
Add a showMore button that once clicked, will show the hidden rows.

In the css

```
.hidden{display:none}
```

In My collection:
Add a parse method

```
Parse: function(response){
```

// loop thru the tweets  and add a hidden css class name to tweets greater than 6

```
Tweet.cssClass = "hidden"

return response;
```

}

In the html

```
    {{#each tweet}}
<li class="{{cssClass}}">
<div class='icon'>
      <img src='{{user.profile_image_url}}'></img>
</div>
    <div class='data'>
        <h4>{{user.name}}</h4>
        <p>{{format text}}</p>
        <p class="timestamp"><i>{{friendlyDate}}</i></p>
    </div>
</li>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be 
In the view, create an afterRender method

Determine the height of the twitter box.

Calculate the height of the

rows in sequence and once it gets to the twitter box height, you hide the box.

```
afterRender: function(){
    var twitterHeight = 400;
    var height=0;
    this.$el.find('ul li').each(function(){
    height += $(this).height();
     })
    If(height>twitterHeight){
        $(this).hide();
    }
```

}

Comment: thanks for you answer so much..but when I tried this approach it seems that the hide method did not work and all the 20 tweets still appear.what is the problem? @GeeDawg

Comment: Which part did not work? Is it getting to the afterRender method?

Comment: yes it is getting to the afterRender method..I used console.log() statements to track the execution, it printed the height of each twitterbox, the overall height and returned true from comparison but the hide method did not work and all the tweets still appears...note:I have called the afterRender method in render method before "return self;" exactly.. @GeeDawg

Comment: I found the solution in twitter API documentation. in serve.js file I should add 'count' parameter to the timeline end point.with this parameter i can determine the number of tweets that I want to retrieve as follows: client.get('statuses/home_timeline', { count:6 },  function (err, reply) {...}